# SqlTableProfileProvider and custom type property

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm using the SqlTableProfileProvider to store profile data.
It works great for standard fields... 
But I would like to store shopping cart data stored like this:
http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/05/aspnet-creating-shopping-cart-example.html

I'm basicly running into the same problem described in this forum topic:
http://forums.asp.net/p/1065760/1627006.aspx
No resolution on the forum... anyone here done this?

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the"sandbox" SqlTableProfileProvider  is not going to allow me to store other data types in the fields...

So I took the route defined in the bottom of this post.
http://forums.asp.net/p/956974/1649620.aspx#1649620

I added a default sqlprofile provider and store the shopping cart data there.